# Tool for importing CSV files into MySQL database?

Tags: sql, mysql, csv, import, load-data-infile

I've got several CSV files I want to import into a table. They all contain different numbers of columns, so some data will be absent during each import. I need a tool that will let me map which CSV column goes into which MySQL column. Doesn't look like MySQL workbench can do this. What else can I use?

Comment: I would start by adjusting the data with a spread sheet like excel in order to remove the column issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL has the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) syntax:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
 IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

See the documentation about custom data handling.

Comment: What if I want to omit a field in the CSV?

Comment: Read the manual page he already linked which has the syntax for mapping CSV fields to columns. It has examples.

Comment: @Dan: Sorry... it was half way down the page...have to use a dumbie value.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running on a Mac, Sequel Pro is pretty good for this sort of thing (as long as you import each CSV file individually).

http://www.sequelpro.com/