# How would I convert .csv data to mysql?

Tags: mysql, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool for importing CSV files into MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813073/tool-for-importing-csv-files-into-mysql-database)

A guy at work gave me a .csv file with thousands of records in it.  There's about 5 columns (out of 20) that I would love to get inserted into a mysql database.

Any idea how I might go about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html).  The example in the docs for CSV is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

You should remove the `IGNORE 1 LINES` clause if there is no header row in the CSV data.

Also, note that the order of the data in the file should match the order of the columns in the table.  If they do not, you will need to specify the order like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  (column1, column2, ...)
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) or BULK INSERT command